# getting encoding error while storing emails fetched from outlook in python

Tags: python, mongodb, outlook

Getting the below error when trying to save Outlook Mails Info into the MongoDb.
Please Help me out in this issue, Help me out with the following code to encode.Any help will be appreciated.

````
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts;
def emailleri_al(folder):   
    Scrapeddate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y %X")
    messages = folder.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", False)
    sfilter="[SentOn] < Scrapeddate"
    for message2 in messages.Restrict(sfilter):
        SourceType='EMAIL'
        Subject=message2.Subject
        SourceEmailID=message2.To
        senttime=message2.Senton.strftime("%d-%m-%y %X")
        emailids=message2.EntryID
        emailfrom=message2.Sender
        Emailbody=message2.Body
        collection.insert_one({'SourceType':SourceType,
                                           'SourceEmailID':SourceEmailID,
                                           'Scraped date':Scrapeddate,
                                           'Email Sent Datetime':senttime,
                                           'Email id from':emailfrom,
                                           'Subject':Subject,
                                           'Email Type':'HotList',
                                           'Email Body':Emailbody,
                                           'Emailids':emailids})

       ```
ERROR : InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <COMObject <unknown>>, of type: <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailItem.Sender` is an object of type `AddressEntry`, not a scalar value (such as string, int, or datetime).

Use `MailItem.SenderName` and/or `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`. For the latter property, make sure you get the SMTP address - if `MailItem.SenderEmailType` == "EX", use `MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. Be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions.